# MS Project burndown for outline level

Tags: ms-project, ms-project-2013, burn-charts

I'm working on creating a burndown graph for a large project that I'm trying to schedule, but I don't want the sub-tasks to be counted as a remaining actual task for the burndowns. Is there a method to mark tasks as 'non-countable' or something for this field?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I may have found a work around for my issue, in the [post here](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/remaining-actual-tasks-field-7db366e1-021c-4bbe-8138-874f8b385d6b)

There is a tip at the bottom claiming: "assigned actual work that is equal to the Work field." This seems to fix things from a reporting stand point on the task usage screen and the burn-down graph. I have to test to see if it marks the task 100% complete though, which is not what I want to do.